# Fixed host name for Dataproc component gateway

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Is it possible to use a fixed host name for Dataproc component gateway? By default, Dataproc component gateway can be accessed in URLs like `https://42qlunruwrdhhauh3sryzzsz5a-dot-us-central1.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/jupyter/`. I noticed that it is defined as as custom metadata key `dataproc-notebooks-url` in compute but could not find any way to change it in Dataproc init script. Is it possible to use a fixed name e.g. `https://some-fixed-name-dot-us-central1.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/jupyter/`. The issue is that the name is auto-generated every time a cluster gets re-created but I would like to access notebooks in a fixed url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host name is encoded from the cluster URI `projects/<project>/regions/<region>/clusters/<cluster>`, so if you recreate the cluster in the same project, region and with the same name, you should be able to get the same component gateway URL. But clusters with different names will get different URLs, that's by design.